# Иероглифы на телефоне

Tags: reactjs

Загружаю json из файла и использую эти данные на сайте.

Весь текст отображается по русски, на именно данные из файла иероглифами когда захожу с телефона.

С ПК такого нет.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Кодировка страницы задана в html-теге?

Comment: Хм....вчера пробовал вставить <meta charset="utf-8">, не помогало, а сегодня вставил и все Ок. Спасибо